# How do I combine custom basic authentication and forms authentication in my Azure web role?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, authentication, azure

I have a REST web service protected with [custom basic authentication](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/). Now I need to add several web pages to that service so that users can get their usage stats just using their browser.

The "web service" should have accounts separate from the "stats pages" accounts. I guess I have to use forms authentication for the "stats pages".

So my service can get POST requests at `/ProcessData` path and such accesses are secure with custom basic authentication and I want to add a page served when user opens `/Profile` path in his browser and looks like that access should be secured with forms authentication.

How do I use these two authentication methods for the same web site? Is there some easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **believe** that you will either:

have to define separate end-points (with different ports) for separate pages, that way you can split up your authentication per endpoint

or

write a custom authentication provider that delegates authentication to either forms or your own, based upon the url targets

Comment: How would I do such delegation?